# Dynamic ComboBox in R GUI Development

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

I am trying to create a simple GUI in R. In this GUI I want to have two combobox, 1) List of data frame from the current workspace 2) Names of variable corresponding to the data frame selected in first combobox. I am trying to use gWidgets library but I am not sure how to do it. Can anyone in this forum help me? Thanks

I want SourceVar as a combo box by taking variable names from inData argument

```
## list data frames in an environment
lsDF <- function(envir=.GlobalEnv) {
 varNames <- ls(envir=envir)
 dfs <- sapply(varNames, function(i) inherits(get(i,envir=envir),"data.frame"))
 varNames[dfs]
}

testFun <- function(inData,sourceVar,targetVar,outData)
{
inData[[targetVar]] <- as.factor(inData[[sourceVar]])
 assign(outData, inData, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

lst <- list()
lst$action <- list(beginning="toFactor(",ending=")")
lst$arguments$inData <- list(type="gcombobox",lsDF())
lst$arguments$sourceVar <- list(type="gedit")
lst$arguments$targetVar <- list(type="gedit")
lst$arguments$outData <- list(type="gedit")
ggenericwidget(lst, container=gwindow("Recode to Factor"))
```

Comment: Provide a reproducible example of what you have tried.

Comment: I have added the example code @G.Grothendieck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `ggenericwidget` (it isn't supported in gWidgets2). Instead create a combobox along the lines of `cb <- gcombobox(character(0), cont=...)` then to populate it call its `[<-` method: e.g., `cb[] <- lsDf()`.

Here is a pattern for you to work with:

```
library(gWidgets2)
data(mtcars)
testdf <- data.frame(a=1:3, b= 1:3)

## list data frame names in envir
dfnms <- names(Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls())) )
lsNms <- function(d, envir=.GlobalEnv)  names(get(d, envir=envir))

w <- gwindow("two combos")
g <- glayout(cont=w)
g[1,1] <- "Data frames:"
g[1,2] <- (dfs <- gcombobox(dfnms, cont=g))
g[2,1] <- "Variables:"
g[2,2] <- (vnames <- gcombobox(character(0), cont=g))

addHandlerChanged(dfs, handler=function(...)  vnames[] <- lsNms(svalue(dfs)))
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more. @jverzani

Comment: Tried to run the code but getting errors: "No toolkit packages are installed" Error in UseMethod(".gwindow"). Do I need to install other libraries along with gWidgets2? Thanks

Comment: Yes, an underlying toolkit interface which is either `gWidgets2RGtk2` (for use with `RGtk2`) or  `gWidgets2tcltk`.